# IIS7 proctect an ASP MVC website already using form authentication with basic auth

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I would to protect a whole website with a basic authentication or by Ip addresses.

But the website in asp mvc already use form authentication.

I mean protect the website with a basic auth then once connected use the normal form authentication + DB system.

I want to prevent people and robot acces a website version not yet finished.

I tryed Ip restriction in IIS but i can't refuse ALL IP, juste some Ip ranges (thats so stupid...)

Activate basic and form authentication at the same time doesnt work neither...

what can i do??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tryed Ip restriction in IIS but i
>   can't refuse ALL IP, juste some Ip
>   ranges (thats so stupid...)

You can do this, I think you have to change the mode from allow by default to deny by default, using `Edit Feature Settings` on the right under actions.

Comment: Yeah lol I saw this window just after... I think i was a little bit tired... Thank you, maybe this will help some other people ;)